# How do I use CSS to centre this content?

Tags: html, css

Apologies for the slightly vague question, but the content is quite specific. I've been playing with a number of different approaches, and I'm really struggling to achieve the desired results.

So I have a collection of photos to display, and this collection will either have one or two photos. These need to be displayed alongside each other and centred on the page. If there is only one photo, then it should be shown on its own and centred on the page. Each photo comes with a title that needs to be displayed above it, and a description that needs to be shown below it.

So it'll either look like this (but centred):

[image: Example of a single photo.]

Or it'll look like this (but centred):

[image: Example of two photos.]

I've played with an outer container div with a margin of auto 0, and I've played around with tables, but I'm struggling with (a) getting them centred, and then (b) being able to have one or two photos (although I could potentially deal with this in code, as this is an MVC view).

I'm a little rusty with CSS, so any and all help and advice much appreciated!

Comment: can you please share your html/css code

Comment: Can you add a fiddle?

Also, have you tried text-align:center on your container div css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is to `text-align:center` a containing element and `text-align:left` the children, for example [**see demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/G94Kz/) or code below.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><h3>Title</h3><img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/abstract/1"/><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p></li>
    <li><h3>Title</h3><img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/abstract/2"/><p>Description</p></li>
    <li><h3>Title</h3><img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/abstract/3"/><p>Description Description Description Description</p></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    text-align:center;
}

li {
    text-align:left;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    max-width:150px;
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

Comment: I couldn't use this because I needed the HTML to work within a Word document. I didn't mention this in my question, though, and I think it's the most elegant solution and it takes the title, photo and description into account, so marking this one as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Put them in a container so that if there is not two images then the container width is the width of the one image then put this style on the container:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Or add `align='center'` to the container

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/c8p6G/

Comment: Thanks Oliver. I'm more rusty than I'd realised - I was using "auto 0" and couldn't work out why it wasn't centering!

Comment: Just spotted your jsFiddle example after your edit and that's even better - no need to set the width - thanks!

Comment: @OliverCole it is not usually considered good practice to ask for answers to be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Finally worked it out!

```
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.photo{
    display: inline-block;
}

.detail {
    text-align: left;
}

<div class="container" align="center">
    <div class="photo">
        <div class="detail">TITLE</div>
        <div class="detail">
            <img src="http://www.desktopas.com/files/2013/06/Images-1920x1200.jpg" width="200px" />
        </div>
        <div class="detail">Description</div>
    </div>
    <div class="photo">
        <div class="detail">TITLE</div>
        <div class="detail">
            <img src="http://www.desktopas.com/files/2013/06/Images-1920x1200.jpg" width="200px" />
        </div>
        <div class="detail">Description</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/c8p6G/).

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use li for rather div

```
<ul>
  <li>
      <h2> Title here</h2>
      <img src="img.jpg" alt="" />
      <p> descriptions here here</p>
  </li>
 <li>
      <h2> Title here</h2>
      <img src="img.jpg" alt="" />
      <p> descriptions here here</p>
  </li>
  <li>
      <h2> Title here</h2>
      <img src="img.jpg" alt="" />
      <p> descriptions here here</p>
  </li>
</ul>


ul{ display: block; text-align:center; }
ul li { display: inline-block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I went back to my CSS and realised straight away that my attempt at a solution using a table  had some mistakes. It was actually very stupidly simple! I'd still like to know if this is possible with div tags instead, though - I'm sure it will be.

With the following, I can choose whether or not to output the second td..

```
<table style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <tr>
        <td style="background: #EEEEEE">
            <div>Title</div>
            <div>PHOTO</div>
            <div>Description Description Description Description Description Description Description </div>
        </td>
        <td style="background: #AAAAAA">
            <div>Title</div>
            <div>PHOTO</div>
            <div>Description Description Description Description Description Description Description </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Should this be an edit to your question, rather than an answer?